# Gulp error: The following tasks did not complete: default, sass

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, gulp

I have created a gulpfile.js file for a project I'm building. When I try to run it, I get this error.

```
[18:29:03] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\codeprojects\antenna\gulpfile.js
[18:29:03] Starting 'default'...
[18:29:03] Starting 'sass'...
[18:29:03] The following tasks did not complete: default, sass
[18:29:03] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

Here is my gulpfile.js code

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src('public/stylesheets/style.scss')
      .pipe(plumber())
      .pipe(sass())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('public/stylesheets'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('public/stylesheets/*.scss', ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('sass', 'watch'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('public/stylesheets/style.scss')  // return added here
      .pipe(plumber())
      .pipe(sass())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('public/stylesheets'));
});

// the return above will suffice to "signal async completion"

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    // gulp.watch('public/stylesheets/*.scss', ['sass']);  // old gulp v3 synatx
    gulp.watch('public/stylesheets/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'));  // v4 syntax
});
```

Also, you will want to switch to the plugin `gulp-dart-sass` instead of `gulp-sass`.  It supports more recent features like `@use` for example.